# "An AJAX HTTP error occurred.HTTP Result Code: 200"

Tags: ajax, http-request

I'm new to Drupal, and I'm working with a Drupal site that someone else wrote. From the admin menu, when I go to Structure -> Pages -> Edit Content -> Gear Menu -> Edit (or Settings), Drupal throws up this error:

> "An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging
>   information follows. Path:
>   /panels/ajax/editor/edit-pane/panel_context%3Apage-join_step_two%3Apage_join_step_two_panel_context/4
>   [...] RESPONSE = nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullfalseCancelled: Error
>   bad character content for element
>   'data_key'***_*__*_*__*_***_nullnullnullfalsenullnull"

The code is also inserting the line

> "RESPONSE = nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullfalseCancelled: Error bad
>   character content for element 'data_key' ***_*__*_*__*_*_**
>   nullnullnullfalsenullnull"

at the bottom of every page.

I know that Firebug can cause the Ajax HTTP 200 error, but I don't have it installed. I've spent hours looking through help pages for this error, and nothing has worked. Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

we need to uncomment .htaccess file in php_value auto_append_file none may be it work.
in ajax return value must be defined.if not exist show this kind of error.clear cache.
 one other solution if you working on the local you need to disable newest module than check it[first you need to take DB backup].

Comment: Please use proper punctuation (space before opening and after closing parenthesis, space after dot and comma, etc.) and letter case. It'll make your poss easier to read. Also, use \` to mark parts that re code, for example \`php_value auto_append_file\` to make it look like this: `php_value auto_append_file`

Answer (score 0):

Ajax HTTP 200 error is generic error and there is not enough info to properly solve it.

You'll need to:

```
grep -r "find in files" .
```

in the code base the string `data_key` (or whatever is printed) and can then debug from there.

Comment: This question was asked on asked Aug 13 '12 at 1:16 with 2474 views till now.

Comment: Regardless, the answer may help someone else looking with a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

- Just disable recently enabled module. or
- May be this error comes to the jQuery module 1.8, not come in 1.7 so check it updated or not.
- Every module start with  `<?php`. just check this line.

This seems to have occurred because of a `Javascript` conflict with some other module or theme.

Many users solved the issue by doing the following;

- Removing the Drupal for Firebug addon (This did the trick for a majority of the users who reported the issue).
- Disabling Firebug.
- Flushing the theme's cache.
- Uninstalling Jquery UI and Jquery Update modules.
- Removing the Twitter Profile module solved the issue for a small number of users.
- Disabling the Theme Developer module solved the issues for a user.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Drupal Answers. Can you please edit your answer to make it clearer.

Comment: after edited. look once it working or not

Answer (score 0):

> Error bad character content for element

means there is a validation error in your XML while parsing the file or response.

This could be related to some external service or custom module breaking Drupal instance.

The problem can be tracked by looking for some specifics in the database, e.g.:

```
drush sql-dump --ordered-dump | grep data_key
```